# Excel moving a quantity and a cell of data to another sheet based on the quantity

Tags: excel, formula

I want to move two cells of data to another sheet within the same workbook. I want to move them based on the quantity of A2:A77 but ignoring blanks and 0. If the quantity cell (A2:A77) is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9* i then want the adjacent cell and the quantity to be moved to another sheet. I am not sure which formula is best to use?

Tim

Answer (score 0):

In sheet2 use below formula.

```
=IF(Sheet1!A2>=1,Sheet1!A2,"")
```

If you want the result as list then use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A77,Sheet1!A2:A77>=1,"")
```